# Is there any possibility to create multiple project name with different bundle id from a same code with the help of any scripted code in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, white-labelling

I have a Project ex."MyApp" with bundle id "com.ios.MyApp". now i want to create multiple App ex.(100's app )with the same code with different App Name with different bundle id such as same concept of white label.
Any one have idea, this process happen through any scripted code which is automatically change the App name from Xcode and bundle id and upload it on testflight ..
I know this entire thing happen or not with Automated Scripting but whatever you can help on this topic or suggest on this , you are most welcome and thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's possible by using targets, but managing 100+ targets is going to be very painful, and Apple is cracking on these kinds of apps, so you might get most of your apps rejected from the store.

Comment: It's also possible using `.xcconfig` files. But it really sounds like what you want to do isn't quite ethical… and like EmilioPelaez said, Apple doesn't like those copy&paste apps and you are likely to get rejected after submitting a few of those.

Answer (score 1):

I Could split your question into two parts:

1- How can I create different application based on the same code base ?

- Answer: It's the Targets. 
  This [reference](https://medium.com/@andersongusmao/xcode-targets-with-multiples-build-configuration-90a575ddc687) has simple steps demonstrate how to create more targets(Each contains its own Bundle Identifier), and you can add custom build configurations and customize the parts that you prefer foreach target.

2- How can I change the bundle identifier using a remote script ?

- Answer: It is not actually the common usable scenario.
  The approach that may concern with this, It is CI (Continuous Integration) as there are scripts to choose which target to build and release among the existence created targets. The following lines can help:

  1. [Using Faslane tool with jenkines](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/build-it-test-it-deliver-it-complete-ios-guide-on-continuous-delivery-with-fastlane-and-jenkins-cbe44e996ac5)
  2. [Using Pre-action scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689934/is-there-a-way-of-automatically-writing-custom-values-to-the-bundles-plist-dur)
  3. Your final try, may you need to build the app your self without Xcode building system at all, Check this [reference](https://medium.com/@vojtastavik/building-an-ios-app-without-xcodes-build-system-d3e5ca86d30d)

If you need more help, Could you specify the exact usage from that case ? 
As for sure Apple doesn't let you to publish the exact same application more than one time (even if using different Bundle Identifier)